# Finding events to be processed in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, asp.net-ajax

On PostBack, from clicking on an ImageButton, it first hits

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Then it hits

```
protected void ImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

My problem is that in my Page_Load it refreshes a ListBox before the selected items can be processed by ImageButton_Click.

Is there a way to tell what events are yet to be processed, so I can handle them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populate/databind your ListBox within Page_Load only on the first load, not after postback. Viewstate will maintain the items in your ListBox subsequently.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if(!IsPostBack) //if not postback
    {
       //populate your listbox
    }

}
```

Here's a good read on the Page's Lifecycle, you'll understand the sequence/order of page/child-controls' events and their purposes.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx
```

Comment: Beat me to it!  Great answer.

Comment: @JM: Thanks, quite a standard answer most guys will be able to give :P

Comment: The problem is that the Page_Load is that of a ascx custom control, so everything is postback -- Hmmm, I'll figure something out.

Comment: @Matt, if you're loading your ASCX in page_load, I'd refactor and let the ASCX control its own state rather than let the parent page control its state... if that's the problem...  you might want to post a diff question to elaborate on your page's design.